# Replacing text adds new lines and is not ideal

Tags: c#

I have a json file that is generated by Azure for a resource

This has /n as the line delimiter rather than /r/n

I need to go through the file and any line that contains PrincipleId needs to be changed so that the principleId value is null

```
  "identity": {
                "principalId": "41a0a189-06dc-49a9-a178-7ade3e4ca587",
                "tenantId": "3710dce5-88c6-434d-89e8-232bb0d52601",
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
```

Would become

```
 "identity": {
                "principalId": null,
                "tenantId": null,
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
```

Ideally I would like to keep the spacing, but I wont know what the spacing will be as the indenting could differ

My current implementation is below

Whilst this does work in terms of the replacement, it adds line gaps after every line

```
            var lines = text.SplitIntoList(StringSplitOptions.None, "\n");
            for (var lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < lines.Count; lineIndex++)
            {
                var line = lines[lineIndex];
                if (line.Contains("\"principalId\": "))
                {
                    line = "\"principalId\": null,";
                    lines[lineIndex] = line;
                }
            }

            var array = lines.ToArray();
            File.WriteAllLines(file, array);
```

Is there a better solution?

How can I maintain the spacing?

Paul

Comment: Wouldn't `File.WriteAllText(file, string.Join("\n", lines));` do the job?

Comment: Is it an option for you to deserialize the json? You could then clear the properties you want to become null and then serialize it back to json.

Comment: I second the idea of deserializing the JSON. If the contract is "the remote server returns JSON", `\n` vs `\r\n` or indeed no line breaks at all is an implementation detail subject to change.

Comment: I dont have any control over the structure of this json though as its a template generated by Microsoft which has loads of properties in it